# Xcode warns me of implicit declaration of 'malloc' but stdlib.h is included in header

Tags: xcode

I am trying to create a stack data type in C in Xcode, therefore using a stack init function.

The following is found in DeckStack.c

```
#define DS DeckStack

#include "DeckStack.h"


struct _DeckStack {
    void *top;
    void *cards[40];
};


DeckStack* stack_init(void) {
    DS *new_deckStack = NULL;

    new_deckStack = (DS*) malloc(sizeof(DS));
    
    return new_deckStack;
}
```

But Xcode is complaining about the implicit declaration of malloc, yet stdlib.h is included in DeckStack.h:

```
#ifndef DeckStack_h
#define DeckStack_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _DeckStack DeckStack;


/* @brief
 
* Creates a new deck
 
*/
DeckStack* stack_init(void);

#endif /* DeckStack_h */
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just press enter a few times and the .c file will update itself with the contents of the header.